# Why does testmysite claim that my website is slow?

Tags: javascript, optimization

The website [testmysite](https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/intl/en-gb/feature/testmysite/) claims that the website I'm working on is very slow, namely 9.8 seconds on 4g which is ridiculous.

My webapp requests geolocation first, but denies it immediately, so this is not where the slowness comes from.
The site is server-rendered, and sends scripts to the client to optimise.

The [bundle analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) is very dubious.
It claims that my total bundle size would be 750kb, but I strongly doubt that this is the case.

Even if it turns out that the testmysite is not a reliable source, I'd like to know why it says that my website is so slow, and what I can actually do to improve.

My vendor node modules are chunk split, because I want the browser to cache them individually.

My website is deployed here: https://zwoop-website-v001.herokuapp.com

Note that loading may take some time because I use the free service and the server falls asleep often.

Edit: my performance tab shows the following in Chrome:

[image]

I have really zero idea why that website says that my site is slow... 
But if the measurement is used by search engines, then I do care.

*** Answer: *** 
I just voted to re-open this question as @slebetman has helped me to troubleshoot some issues and I'd just like to formulate an answer.
First thing to note is that the free Heroku server that I run in production is located in Europe (this was an option you could choose), and it is unclear where the server from testmysite is located. @slebetman was located in East-Asia when running his test.
@slebetman mentioned that the network tab indicated for him a very slow load time for loading fonts (woff2), of about 2 seconds. This didn't occur for me, but as it turns out, these are font-awesome icons that are loaded from a CDN.
So while there is the logical thought of looking at performance in terms of script loading, interpretation and rendering, there may additionally be a latency issue related to third-party resources that are downloaded from another server. Even when your website is fast, you don't actually know if you have imported some module that requests additional resources.
Either of these things can be tracked through the performance or network tab of Google Chrome. An additional tip is to mimick a slow network (although I don't think this would actually track all problems that may occur on the network in terms of redirects, DNS resolutions etc as @slebetman mentions could be the case as well).

Comment: *Note that loading may take some time because I use the free service and the server falls asleep often.* not much to add. Also have a look at the consoles performance tab, it already has everything you need.

Comment: @JonasWilms It wasn't asleep while I did the test though. Also that performance tab doesn't mention real problems as I updated in my question. I understand that it is a difficult to answer question, but the tooling to fix this doesn't correspond to that test so it is difficult to solve.

Comment: Fun fact: I have websites that load in 200ms :) Oh and that tab shows much more if you dig into it. You can even simulate slow network connections too.

Comment: @JonasWilms Nice. I'm also planning to optimize lazy-loading components. The first run on scripts will take about 300-400ms, but that should only be the first time. Paints are ridiculously fast. I really have no idea. Thanks for notifying me about that tab.

Comment: I am unable to consistently load your website in less than 2s. The fastest I've ever got was around 980ms but only once. Now that I've refreshed it several times to wake up your server let's see the next 10 load times: 3772ms, 5972ms, 5415ms, 3946ms, 8753ms (8 SECONDS!), 3538ms, 3498ms, 3297ms, 4881ms, 5446ms. So testmysite is not lying. Tested at home via a 100Mbps connection

Comment: .. oh. Those loads were with caching disabled via developer tool network tab in Chrome

Comment: @slebetman I don't see that in the performance tab. The JS script bundles are not big and the painting should really not be much. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Not really. Maybe you can bundle some of your js files as you now have quite high HTTP header overhead - 40+ files is quite excessive. But to me it just looks like a slow server (not necessarily slow CPU, can be slow network since I'm in East Asia and the server doesn't have a fast route to here)

Comment: Screenshot of my performance tab:  https://static.rcgroups.net/forums/attachments/2/6/7/7/4/4/a12454593-125-Screenshot%202019-08-21%20at%205.12.58%20AM.png

Comment: @slebetman But your screenshot shows for the majority idle time? The script loading / rendering doesn't seem to take long.

Comment: Yes but that idle time does not come at the end of page load. It is between page start loading and last item of the page load - it is time waiting for data to arrive from the internet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198206/discussion-between-trace-and-slebetman).

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that the free Heroku server that I run in production is located in Europe (this was an option you could choose), and it is unclear where the server from testmysite is located.
@slebetman was located in East-Asia when running his test.
@slebetman mentioned that the network tab indicated for him a very slow load time for loading fonts (woff2), of about 2 seconds. This didn't occur for me, but as it turns out, these are font-awesome icons that are loaded from a CDN.

So while there is the logical thought of looking at performance in terms of script loading, interpretation and rendering, there may additionally be a latency issue related to third-party resources that are downloaded from another server. Even when your website is fast, you don't actually know if you have imported some module that requests additional resources.
Either of these things can be tracked through the performance or network tab of Google Chrome. An additional tip is to mimick a slow network (although I don't think this would actually track all problems that may occur on the network in terms of redirects, DNS resolutions etc as @slebetman mentions could be the case as well).